# Enable journalctl within Ubuntu container

Tags: iptables, docker, netfilter, journalctl

I've got an Ubuntu 22.04 container running on a MacOS host.  Inside the container, I'm fiddling with routing and would like to add some `-j LOG` rules to `iptables` to see where my packets are going.  Unfortunatey, `journalctl` doesn't exist inside of my container.

Is there a way to enable `journalctl`?  If not, is there another way for me to see the netfilter logs?